# Raspberry pi system temperature error message

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, operating-system

raspberry pi System temperature will not retrieve from the script

```
import datetime
import os

Time_Stamp = datetime.datetime.now()
temp = os.popen("cat /sys/class/thermal/temp").readline()
RPi_Temp = int(temp) / 1000
```

The above lines is not retrieve the temperature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mention path `"cat /sys/class/thermal/temp"` is wrong:

```
Time_Stamp = datetime.datetime.now()
temp = os.popen("cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp").readline()
RPi_Temp = int(temp) / 1000
```